# Angular 5 firebase database get one item

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I got lots of projects :

```
export class Project {
  $key: string;
  file: File;
  name: string;
  title: string;
  cat: string;
  url: string;
  progress: number;
  createdAt: Date = new Date();

  constructor(file: File) {
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

I upload them all to :

```
  uploads: Observable<Project[]>;

  private saveFileData(upload: Project) {
    this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/project`).push(upload);
}
```

And then I am trying to get one :

```
 uploads: Observable<Project[]>;
getOne(){
  this.uploads = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/project/${this.projectId}`);
}
```

In this case I get error on this.uploads

> (Angularfirelist is not assignable to Observable.)

Then I tried this :

```
  uploads: AngularFireList<Project[]>;

getOne(){
  this.uploads = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/project/${this.projectId}`);
}
```

Error :

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe
>   'AsyncPipe'

**How to get that one project ?**

Answer (score 1):

Add `valueChanges()`to get only the data, or `snapshotChanges()` to get data's payload:

```
this.uploads = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/project/${this.projectId}`).valueChanges();
```

Comment: It gets all strings as new objects.

Comment: But you use `async` pipe in template like -  `<div *ngFor="let item of uploads | async">`?

Comment: I assume i need to use object not a list if I want to show only one

Comment: So you could do `{{ uploads | async }}`

Comment: Yes it worked, next question if you can help : How do I upload my project like this : 

project1/projec1 values,
project2/project2 values,

Comment: If you save a variable with current project and concatenate it to the query, that would work, but if user logs out and logs in, it starts again from 1, so you probably need to save the last number in db. But this sounds more like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I think not, because I upload my projects with their keys now into project db. So I only need add procet/project(number)/projectlist

Comment: Maybe I dont fully understand, but Firebase generates unique keys, so why dont use those? You could later query them by timestamp if you add it